# WP7 crash report ".__c__DisplayClass1._Run_b__0"

Tags: windows-phone-7, crash, crash-reports

I'm new to analyzing crash reports so bear with me please.
I got this crash report:

```
Frame    Image             Function                                           

    Offset    
0        coredll.dll       xxx_RaiseException                                     19        
1        mscoree3_7.dll                                                           520892    
2        mscoree3_7.dll                                                           461967    
3        mscoree3_7.dll                                                           534468    
4                          TransitionStub                                         0         
5                          .__c__DisplayClass1._Run_b__0                          140       
6                          .__c__DisplayClassa._InvokeGetResponseCallback_b__8    76        
7                          .WorkItem.WaitCallback_Context                         104       
8                          System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run                  324       
9                          .WorkItem.doWork                                       220       
10                         System.Threading.Timer.ring                            296       
11       mscoree3_7.dll                                                           507848    
12       mscoree3_7.dll                                                           509212    
13       mscoree3_7.dll                                                           440663    
14       mscoree3_7.dll                                                           440417    
15       mscoree3_7.dll                                                           439375    
16       mscoree3_7.dll                                                           317155    
17       coredll.dll       ThreadBaseFunc                                         144
```

What I can understand is that the lines 5 and 6 are pointing to the cause of the crash.
Does this trace mean that a Timer Triggered event is causing the issue?
If so, my app does not have any Timer-Triggered events, only an Ad SDK that is set to refresh the Ad every 30 seconds.
Is it possible that when the Ad control fails to get the Ad (because of no Internet connectivity) it does this crash?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Can you post some code? Preferably a [simple, self-contained, correct example](http://sscce.org/)

Comment: Without the code that goes with it, this crash report is meaningless. It appears you have an issue with a thread accessing something it shouldn't (`.WorkItem.doWork` and `System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run`), though.

Comment: Hi,
Thanks for the quick replies.
The problem is that I do not have such things in the app as (.WorkItem.doWork nor System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run) in the code. I am leaning more towards the Ad control as the cause of the issue.
The app is really simple, just to convert numbers from one number system to the other.
Anyway, I'll post some code whenever I get home as I don't have it here.

Comment: Looking at this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9643896/httpwebrequest-returns-null-responsestatuscode I think its the issue of the Ad control because my code does not call any web requests.

Comment: If you think it's your ad control. you may want to confirm that you have the correct fields are filled out for your ad control. That you used to get from Pub Center but now I believe you can get that information from Windows Phone Dev Center. Good luck.